# É certo utilizar a tag <i> para ícones e não para itálico?

Tags: html, html5

Atualmente temos percebido que muita gente vem utilizando a tag `<i>` para ícones e não para itálico. Se ainda estivéssemos na era pré-HTML5 isso estaria totalmente errado.

Segundo especificação da tag `<i>` do HTML5, agora ela é utilizada para o texto de uma "voz alternativa", como palavras estrangeiras transliteradas, termos técnicos e tipografias.

Então, se utilizarmos Icon Fonts, que são tipografias de imagens, o código continuará semanticamente correto, certo?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Em HTML4, a tag `<i>` significava itálico. Na última década, o movimento dos padrões web lutou para que os desenvolvedores passassem a separar estrutura de estilo, que é de responsabilidade do CSS. Porém seria complicado remover essa tag. Mesmo que fosse retirada da especificação, nenhum fabricante de browser em sã consciência eliminaria o suporte, pois isso quebraria vários sites já existentes. Então deram "um jeitinho": um novo significado para o elemento.

Traduzindo do [guia de markup do w3c](http://dev.w3.org/html5/markup/i.html):

> O elemento i representa um trecho de texto destacado de seu contexto sem que transmita ênfase ou importância adicional, e para o qual a convenção tipográfica de apresentação é texto em itálico; por exemplo, um termo de uma taxonomia, um termo técnico, uma expressão idiomática de outra língua, um pensamento ou o nome de um navio.

Não diz se deve ou não ser utilizada para ícones, como faz o bootstrap. No campo da marcação semântica, sempre há controvérsias.

Comment: Resumindo: não é certo, mas como não há outra forma de se fazer...

Comment: Na verdade há sim: que tal um span? A escolha do i foi por economia de caracteres, acho.

Comment: O <span> não irá agregar semântica a página. Mas concordo que nenhuma semântica é melhor que uma semântica errada.

Comment: Por que não usar o <img> ?

Comment: Mas não estamos falando de ícones que são caracteres de fontes de símbolos? `<img>` não funcionaria, não são imagens.

Comment: É verdade, falha minha. Fugi ao contexto.

Comment: Semanticamente falando, é _errado_ usar `<i></i>` e `<b></b>`. Desenvolvedores do Bootstrap já afirmaram que a usam unicamente por redução de caracteres. Idealmente o mais próximo seria usar mesmo `<span></span>`, mas ninguém é obrigado a fazê-lo.

Answer (score 13):

## Introdução

A primeira vez que me apercebi do uso da tag `<i></i>` para aplicar icons, mais propriamente os que constam de uma fonte (tipo de letra), foi através do Bootstrap.

Alguns exemplos são a [FontAwesome](http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/) e a [Glyphish](http://www.glyphish.com/) que usam tipos de letra para fornecer icons.

Não posso dizer que tenha concordado com a ideia, mas na altura até nem estava mal pensado. Foi uma "vitória" para eles em termos de desempenho (performance):

- `i` como abreviatura de icon;
- tag com um tamanho super reduzido em relação às outras.

Contudo, actualmente, [até a Bootstrap já deixou essa prática](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#glyphicons) e recorre à tag `<span></span>` para apresentar icons.

---

## Oficialmente

Mediante o que pode ser lido no [site da W3C](http://dev.w3.org/html5/markup/i.html), a tag `<i></i>` tem um objectivo bem definido:

> Although previous versions of HTML defined the i element only in presentational terms, the element has now been given the specific semantic purpose of representing text “offset from its surrounding content without conveying any extra emphasis or importance, and for which the conventional typographic presentation is italic text”.

Que se traduz em:

> Embora versões anteriores do HTML tenham definido o elemento i somente em termos de apresentação, o elemento tem agora propósito semântico específico de representar texto "deslocamento de seu conteúdo envolvente sem transmitir qualquer ênfase extra ou importância, e para o qual a apresentação tipográfica convencional é itálico texto ".

---

## Resposta à pergunta

> Então, se utilizarmos Icon Fonts, que são tipografias de imagens, o código continuará semanticamente correto, certo?

Tecnicamente não existe texto dentro da tag, pelo que nada vai ser lido da mesma, o que existe no caso particular do uso desta tag para apresentar icons é uma representação visual de uma imagem que está a ser aplicada via CSS.

Semanticamente é errado porque a tag não está a representar texto.

Comment: Então hoje a melhor opção para ícones é mesmo o <span> ?

Comment: Por que não utilizar o <img> ?

Comment: @JeanLucasdeCarvalho Dizer "melhor opção" é um pouco um jogo de opiniões, mas parece-me ser uma boa alternativa, quando falamos de icons provenientes de fontes. A tag `img` é suposto apresentar uma imagem através da sua `src`, pelo menos o navegador assim o espera...

Comment: sim. Falha minha quanto a tag <img>. Fugi ao contexto. Acabei esquecendo que minha pergunta estava limitada aos ícones provenientes de fontes.

Comment: `<i>` e `<span>` são usadas porque a propriedade `backgroud` de CSS é definida como a imagem. Usar `<img>` sem atributo `src` como se fosse `<i>` seria ainda pior, semanticamente falando e até causar bugs na aparência em diferentes navegadores. O código HTML não vai nem mesmo ser validado

Answer (score 2):

Segundo a W3C, as tags `<i>` e `<b>` não necessariamente são utilizados como Itálico e Negrito.

Veja uma [explicação coerente](http://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-b-and-i-tags) e acredito que você vai saber utilizar da melhor forma:

[Esse outro](http://davidwalsh.name/font-awesome-tags) explica como você utilizar para ícones:

Comment: Sim, eu sei como utilizá-las para ícones. A questão na verdade é: isso é correto?

Comment: não tem problema quanto a utilização do <i> ele apenas para icones, a w3c recomenda utilizar para destacar uma parte do texto, ou talvez um texto em outra língua, mas ele é um elemento de bloco assim como span!

Comment: @alexandesigner sempre que possivel é bom traduzir algum conreudo de links externos, para a resposta ficar mais completa e para ajudar outros que procuram em Português.

Comment: @Sergio Ok Sérgio, obrigado pela dica.. estou experimentando e pretendo contribuir e aprender bastante!

Comment: Uma observação: "mas ele é um elemento de bloco assim como span!" - Não, `<i>` por padrão é um elemento `inline` assim como `<span>`, e não de bloco.

Answer (score 1):

Semânticamente falando, a tag `<i>` é usada para representar texto. Se o que queremos apresentar é apenas uma imagem e não texto, então a tag `<img>` é a mais adequada para esse efeito. Normalmente os ícones aparecem no documento por uma questão de apresentação apenas, e portanto  sendo um artefacto meramente de apresentação, deveriam ser inseridos com CSS.

É claro que isso é tudo muito bonito na teoria, mas em termos práticos `<i>` acaba por ser jeitoso para colocar ícones.

Answer (score 1):

Já vi o uso da `<i>` para ícones, mas não considero semântico.

Ícones não se encaixam na descrição de uso da tag `<i>`, portanto ainda considero mais adequado o uso de algum elemento sem valor semântico. No caso o `<span>`

Answer (score 0):

Segundo a W3C, a tag `<i>`, deve ser utilizada para destacar parte do texto *inline* (na mesma linha). O padrão é formatar o texto em itálico.

Está sendo utilizada para inserir ícones, no lugar da tag `<img>` por pura economia de digitação e não é considerada uma *boa prática*, pois não melhora em nada a performance e confunde o entendimento do código.

Answer (score 0):

O certo mesmo é usar para texto em itálico, mas eu geralmente uso para criar ícones nos meus sites.

Algumas tags eu chamo de tags universais, como span, section e principalmente a tag div, eu uso estas tags para qualquer coisa no html. Não é obrigatório você seguir o padrão, no final você que escolhe.

Answer (score 0):

O `<em>` aplica o texto em emfase (itálico) em HTML5. Mas acho que é mais fácil você editar um `<span>` com o CSS, do que recorrer a tag. O `<i>` ainda não foi descontinuado, acho melhor parar de usá-lo

Answer (score 0):

O ideal seria colocar toda a formatação no CSS e deixar somente o básico no HTML.
Então itálico seria somente font:italic
E  indicaria ícones.