# Semanticamente, qual tag devo usar para ícones?

Tags: html, css, html5, css-font-face, semântica

Tenho um menu de navegação com alguns ícones utilizando `@font-face`.
Cada item desse menu tem:

- o ícone (com `::before`);
- texto, explicando qual a função daquele link.

.Acontece que, quando a página for carregada em um dispositivo menor, quero que o texto "desapareça" e seja mostrado somente o ícone. Tenho a seguinte estrutura:

```
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a class='ico-foo' href='#'>Visitar Foo</a></li>
    <li><a class='ico-bar' href='#'>Visitar Bar</a></li>
    <li><a class='ico-foobar' href='#'>Visitar FooBar</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Normal, como a maioria das estruturas. Acontece que, se eu tentar esconder o conteúdo da tag `<a>` o ícone no `::before` não irá aparecer. Por exemplo, tentei usar `text-indent: -999px;` e não funcionou pois o ícone acompanha essa regra e "some".

Pois bem, a solução que encontrei para esconder o texto foi colocar ele dentro de um `<span>`, assim quando a página é aberta em um dispositivo menor eu dou um `display:none` nessa tag `<span>` e assim é mostrado somente os ícones como eu gostaria. A estrutura então:

```
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a class='ico-foo' href='#'><span>Visitar Foo</span></a></li>
    <li><a class='ico-bar' href='#'><span>Visitar Bar</span></a></li>
    <li><a class='ico-foobar' href='#'><span>Visitar FooBar</span></a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Beleza. A minha dúvida é:
Essa é a melhor tag para fazer isto? Estou me preocupando com pouca coisa?

Alguns sites (principalmente os criados usando bootstrap) utilizam a tag  para ícones, mas [segundo essa pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/2800/%C3%89-certo-utilizar-a-tag-i-para-%C3%ADcones-e-n%C3%A3o-para-it%C3%A1lico?rq=1/) o uso é apenas para economizar caracteres.

Alguma sugestão pra fazer isso de uma forma melhor?

Comment: Renang, a minha ideia não funciona tão bem quanto eu pensava. O icon também é apanhado. Acho que o `span` é de facto a melhor opção. Vamos ver o que os demais dizem.

Comment: E um line-height alto com overflow hidden, alguém tentou?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A tag [`<span/>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/HTML/Element/span) é *de facto* a mais utilizada para lidar com problemas como o que referes.

> O elemento HTML `<span>` é um *conteiner* genérico em linha para conteúdo fraseado, que não representa nada por natureza.

É um elemento sem qualquer significado adicional associado ao seu uso, ao contrário de outros elementos como `<em/>` e `<i/>` que têm um significado por trás do seu uso, ou seja, foram criados com um objetivo especifico, ao passo que o elemento `<span/>` foi criado para permitir atribuir formatação via CSS, referenciar idioma, entre outros, a determinado conteúdo sem que este seja influenciado pelo seu uso.

No teu caso em particular pretendes manipular o texto via CSS, nada melhor que o envolver com um `<span>` para abstraíres o impacto do CSS do resto da tua *markup* e focar o mesmo unicamente no texto.

Sobre a forma como estás a agir, o `display:none;` parece-me o melhor percurso a tomar.

Outros métodos carecem alguns cuidados:

- Indentação negativa

  Pode ser utilizado em alguns cenários, por exemplo `text-indent:-999px` mas muito cuidado porque a tela do visitante pode ser maior que o `text-indent` dado e o texto vai aparecer num local inapropriado.
- Tamanho de letra zero

  Pode ser utilizado em alguns cenários, mas os [*crawlers*](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_crawler) <sup>(Inglês)</sup>, como é o caso da Google [consideram isso incorreto](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/66353?hl=pt) e contra as regras de SEO o que vai deixar uma *bandeira* na página de forma negativa.

Comment: A sugestão de indentar o texto não funciona, o ícone está sendo inserido no ::before da tag. Então, minha solução é a mais adequada mesmo? O uso da tag <span> ?

Comment: Sim, eu diria que o que estás a fazer é o melhor que pode ser feito dado o que pretendes. Não estás a elevar a complexidade da markup nem a tirar significado aos elementos de HTML. Está tudo Ok :)

Comment: Se da forma que tens resulta, estares a alterar não ganhas nada a não ser "perder tempo". Precisas de uma `<span>` seja para o icon seja para manipular a visibilidade do texto. Se usas para um ou para outro é irrelevante no que respeita ao código na tua pergunta. Continua a achar que estás bem como estás :)