# Como usar a tag Icon em HTML?

Tags: html, html-tags

Quero usar uma 'flexinha' ao lado do texto do botão. Tentei usar os símbolos do próprio teclado, porém o site que quero inserir não aceita. Posso usar a tag icon, como é usada para botar o logo no titulo do site?

Comment: Olá maiquel, bem vindo ao Stack Overflow. Poderia dá exemplos do que tem tentado?

Comment: Relacionado: [É certo utilizar a tag <i> para ícones e não para itálico?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/2800/%C3%89-certo-utilizar-a-tag-i-para-%C3%ADcones-e-n%C3%A3o-para-it%C3%A1lico)

Answer (score 6):

Desconheço tal tag (icon).
Para inserir um ícone, você pode adicionar o nome da classe do ícone a qualquer elemento HTML `inline`.

Os elementos `<i>` e `<span>` são os mais utilizados para adicionar ícones.

Você deve incluir um arquivo com uma `biblioteca de ícones` para poder utilizar as classes.

Exemplo de biblioteca:

http://fontawesome.io/examples/

Exemplo de utilização:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">


<div><i class="fa fa-home">Home</i></div>
<div><i class="fa fa-search">Busca</i></div>
<div><i class="fa fa-cloud">Nuvem</i></div>
<div><i class="fa fa-trash">Lixo</i></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Segue o exemplo:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<button>
  <i class="fa fa-chevron-down" aria-hidden="true"></i>
  Abrir
</button>
```

Utilizando o `Font Awesome` você consegue adicionar icones ([SITE](http://fontawesome.io))

Lembrando que você tem outras alternativas com o [FONTELLO](http://fontello.com/), com ele, você pode selecionar apenas os icones que irá usar e fazer o download do pacote, utilizando de uma forma similar ao `FontAwesome`

Answer (score 2):

Bom dia!

Eu costumo usar o seguinte formato, por exemplo:

```
<a href="#">
       <i class="fa fa-file-text-o"></i><span>Atendimento<i class="fa fa-angle-down"></i></span>
</a>
```

São famosos 2 tipos de icones, os icones do `Font Awesome` ou os do `Bootstrap`, ai vai de qual você prefere, eu costumo usar o framework `Bootstrap` e usar os icones do `Font Awesome`.

Segue um link do `Font Awesome` de onde tem os icones e de como usa-los.

Icones Disponiveis: http://fontawesome.io/icons/

Como usar: http://fontawesome.io/get-started/

Ao clicar em algum icone, é aberto uma nova pagina explicando como usar aquele icone especifico. Lembrando que é possivel também estilizar com CSS as tags `<i>`.